# Unexpected error forwarding or redirecting to login page

Tags: jsf, error-handling, facelets, j-security-check, viewexpiredexception

I have a JSF app running on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 with Mojarra 2.1.21 and OmniFaces 1.4.1 to handle Ajax errors. The app has both protected and public areas, using form-based-authentication (on a JSF form) with programmatic login.

I'd always get a blank page when user clicks a commandButton on a **protected page** that's expired caused by an underlying **ServletException: Unexpected error forwarding or redirecting to login page.**

Correct me if I'm wrong but from the log, it seems to be due to the web container forwarding to login.xhtml yet still trying to restore the old view - ending up with a ViewExpiredException that it wraps into a ServletException, so no error-page defined in web.xml could be matched and displayed. Here's the exception:

```
    [#|2013-05-07T16:51:12.175+0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=105;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ApplicationDispatcher[] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/login.xhtml - View /login.xhtml could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
    ...
|#]

[#|2013-05-07T16:51:12.176+0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator|_ThreadID=105;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Unexpected error forwarding or redirecting to login page
javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId:/login.xhtml - View /login.xhtml could not be restored.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
    ...
Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/login.xhtml - View /login.xhtml could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    ... 32 more
|#]
```

I've tried for hours catching it a number of ways to no avail:

- Adding `faces-redirect=true` to the login page configuration has no effect as it's not an outcome

> ```
>  <form-login-config>
>         <form-login-page>/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</form-login-page>
>         <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</form-error-page>
>     </form-login-config>
> ```

- Adding a servlet filter to catch rootCause didn't work because container managed security kicks in before the filter, as mentioned on another post

> ```
> @Override
> public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
>     try {
>         chain.doFilter(request, response);
>     } catch (ServletException e) {
>         Throwable rootCause = e.getRootCause();
>         if (rootCause instanceof ViewExpiredException) { // This is true for any FacesException.
>             throw (ViewExpiredException) rootCause; // Throw wrapped ViewExpiredException instead of ServletException.
>         } else if (rootCause instanceof RuntimeException) { // This is true for any FacesException.
>             throw (RuntimeException) rootCause; // Throw wrapped RuntimeException instead of ServletException.
>         } else {
>             throw e;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

- Making `login.xhtml` stateless (via `<f:view transient = "true">`) didn't help because it was the view of the expired page that Faces Servlet was trying to restore.

From numerous posts here on StackOverflow I know there are a few options:

- *Make the login page a non-JSF page*, but I really would like some
  dynamic data on the login page
- *Use a custom error handler*, which
  worked, but it overrides OmniFaces' FullAjaxException handler and no
  longer respects the error-page declarations in web.xml

What I'd like to know is are there any other way to gracefully handle this exception? Either allowing the forwarding to the login page or show an error page. (A non-Ajax equivalent of FullAjaxExceptionHandler would be perfect!)

Many thanks in advance.

My web.xml:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- See annotation declared servlets, converters, and filters in faces and servlet folders -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            1
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/expired.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <!-- SECURITY -->
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>AdminPagesConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>AdminResource</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>CustomerPagesConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>CustomerResource</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/customer/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>CUSTOMER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>App_Realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page><!-- no use for programmatic login -->
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>CUSTOMER</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include below snippet in web.xml. It worked for me

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</location>
</error-page>
```

but comment out

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```